# Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Tags: python, discord

RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.add_cog' was never awaited
Help me fix it:< i am creating bot discord

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from help_cog import help_cog
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='l',intents=intents)
bot.remove_command('help')
bot.add_cog(help_cog(bot))
bot.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```